# Right way to modify a property in a state object?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm working with `react 17.0.2` and `next 12.0.0`, and use `react-date-range` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-range)

I have this 3 states

```
const [calendarDates, setCalendarDates] = useState(null);
const [wasCleared, setWasCleared] = useState(true);
const [focusedRange, setFocusedRange] = useState([0, 0]);
```

Then, when i call the component:

```
          <DateRangePicker
            preventSnapRefocus
            showPreview
            showSelectionPreview
            direction="horizontal"
            focusedRange={focusedRange}
            minDate={new Date()}
            monthDisplayFormat="MMMM yyyy"
            months={2}
            ranges={calendarConfig.calendarDates}
            showDateDisplay={false}
            showMonthAndYearPickers={false}
            weekdayDisplayFormat="EEEEEE"
            onChange={item => handleDatesChange([item.selection])}
            onRangeFocusChange={setFocusedRange} // this is the line what i dont understand
          />
```

I want to change these 3 states for just one, that has in the 3 properties, just like:

```
const [calendarConfig, setCalendarConfig] = useState({
  focusedRange: [0, 0],
  wasCleared: true,
  calendarDates: null
});
```

Now, i want to change this line

```
onRangeFocusChange={setFocusedRange}
```

for this

```
onRangeFocusChange={item => handleFocusedRange(item)}
```

Then, i do:

```
const handleFocusChange = item => {
    setCalendarConfig({
      ...calendarConfig,
      focusedRange: item,
    });
  };
```

but doesn't work.

My question is, what are exactly doing this? `onRangeFocusChange={setFocusedRange}` and how i can replace it, in order to change `calendarConfig.focusedRange`

Comment: Your approach is correct, although nested state is not best practice ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react#51136076)). Why it is failing I cant see right now, but it's probably not directly related to `onRangeFocusChange={item => handleFocusedRange(item)}`

Comment: maybe it's `handleFocusedRange` and `handleFocusChange` diff names problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All seams fine to me, except setting state:

```
  const handleFocusChange = item => {
    setCalendarConfig((prevConfig) => {
      prevConfig.focusedRange = item;
      return prevConfig;
    });
  };
```

Comment: YES! this is the right way, sorry, could you explain to me, or give some link to read, in order to know what are you doing here?

Comment: @AgustinG. Read part about functional updates https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate